# Subscribe to an SNS topic and / or SQS queue in golang?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I know how to do this in java, but I just can't figure it out in Go at all.

All I want to do, is have a way to detect that an item got created in an S3 bucket, then have that trigger an SNS topic, which then notifies me of the file location in S3.

Has anybody got a working example of how I can do the go side of this for subscribing to the SNS topic or the SNS queue if I need one? Because all I seem to be able to find is Java and Node. I can find publish examples for go, but they are of little use to my use case.

Comment: S3 can publish events to SNS when an object gets created with just configuration and no coding. Where is your problem?

Comment: if my answer has worked for you, please mark it as the "correct answer"  i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png

Answer (score 3):

To use SNS you will need a simple HTTP/HTTPS endpoint to receive SNS notifications. Which is divided into two parts (Confirm the subscription and Processing messages from HTTP/HTTPS endpoint)

**1. Confirm the subscription**
Do something as simple as this:

```
func confirmSubscription(subcribeURL string) {
    response, err := http.Get(subcribeURL)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unbale to confirm subscriptions")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Subscription Confirmed sucessfully. %d", response.StatusCode)
    }
}
```

**2. Processing messages from HTTP/HTTPS endpoint**

Parse the request's body, the [documentations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html) mentions how the body should be structured.

**Sources:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html

https://github.com/viveksyngh/aws-sns-subscriber/blob/master/subscriber/subscriber.go

Comment: Ok! Thanks! But I have one more question! SubscribeURL? I've never seen that before, I am SURE I used ARNs for subscribing before, no?

Comment: The SubscribeURL is sent to you in the body during the "confirmation" step. All what you need to do is make a GET request to that URL and you will start receiving messages from SNS as soon as they sent from S3.